# How to convert a String to an XML object in Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I get a SOAP message from a web service, and I can convert the response string to an XML file using the below code. This works fine. But my requirement is not to write the SOAP message to a file. I just need to keep this XML document object in memory, and extract some elements to be used in further processing. However, if I just try to access the document object below, it comes as empty.

Can somebody please tell me how I can convert a `String` to an in-memory XML object (without having to write to a file)?

```
String xmlString = new String(data); 
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  

DocumentBuilder builder;  
try  
{  
    builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();  

    // Use String reader  
    Document document = builder.parse( new InputSource(  
            new StringReader( xmlString ) ) );  

    TransformerFactory tranFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();  
    Transformer aTransformer = tranFactory.newTransformer();  
    Source src = new DOMSource( document );  

    Result dest = new StreamResult( new File( "xmlFileName.xml" ) );  
    aTransformer.transform( src, dest );

}
```

Comment: And what's wrong with `Document document = builder.parse( new InputSource( new StringReader( xmlString ) ) )`??  This is DOM representation of the XML string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the 5 last lines of code, and you'll just have the DOM document in memory. Store this document in some field, rather than in a local variable.

If that isn't sufficient, then please explain, with code, what you mean with *"if I just try to access the document object below, it comes as empty"*.

Comment: op says: "However, if I just try to access the document object below, it comes as empty."

Comment: If it was empty (whatever that might mean), the transformer wouldn't write much to the file. SO the OP is doing something wrong in the code he doesn't show us.

Answer (score 0):

JB Nizet is right, the first steps create a DOM out of `xmlString`. That will load your xmlString (or SOAP message) into an in-memory Document. What the following steps are doing (all the things related with the Transform) is to serialize the DOM to a file (xmlFileName.xml), which is not what you want to do, right?

When you said that your DOM is empty, I think you tried to print out the content of your DOM with `document.toString()`, and returned something like "[document: null]". This doesn't mean your DOM is empty. Actually your DOM contains data. You need now to use the DOM API to get access to the nodes inside your document. Try something like `document.getChildNodes(), document.getElementsByTagName(), etc`

Comment: My bad! I called document.getNodeValue which returned empty. The document had no value but only one child